# How to create a mask for an input?

Tags: angular

How to create a mask for an `input` with Angular 2?

I tried using PrimeNG, however the attribute `required` is not working.
I also Tried `angular2-text-mask`, however it's not working, too.

Any suggestion?

**UPDATE:**

I used this library: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2

1. First, I installed: `npm i angular2-text-mask --save`
2. Then, I included in module:

```html
import MaskedInput  from 'angular2-text-mask'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ FormsModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ MaskedInput ],
  providers:    [ appRoutingProviders ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3. Then, I included in my component:

```html
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [LojaService],
    templateUrl: 'app/admin/loja/loja-form/form.html'

})

export class FormComponent { 
    public mask = ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]

  ...
}
```

4. My `form.html`:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
...

  <input [textMask]="{mask: mask}" [(ngModel)]="myModel" type="text"/>
  
...
</form>
```

5. Result:

[image]

** sorted out! **

I used another solution: a plugin masked jQuery. I did the integration of plugin with Angular 2.

Comment: I'm using angular2-text-mask and it works. Please post your problem and your code.

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs.
You should've import `TextMaskModule` instead of `MaskedInput`

At least it works this way now.